# How to constrain all TableLayout columns to fit in the page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm using a TableLayout containing a row of ImageButtons and a row of TextViews.

The desired outcome is all the images aligned to center, columns distributed evenly, and the texts aligned just below the images. See example below:

[image]

What happens right now is that **one of the images always exceeds the page boundaries**. See image below:
[image: Table example]

Here is the XML code:

```html
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
                <TableRow android:weightSum="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewUrgent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/greyexclamation_trans"
                        android:tooltipText=""
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonRead"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile"
                        android:tooltipText=""
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonReply"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_reply_24"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:tooltipText=""
                        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonForward"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_forward_to_inbox_24"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:tooltipText=""
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:text="text1"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewRead"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:text="text2"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewReply"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:text="text3"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewForward"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:text="text4"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I've used `android:stretchColumns="*"` for the table and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for each of the images.

I've also set an external LinearLayout with `weightSum=1, gravity="center"` and the TableLayout `layout_weight=0.8` so that the table is centered and takes 80% of the page width.
I have then tried both setting `weightSum=1` for the TableRow and each image and text as `layout_weight=0.25`, and setting no `weightSum` at all for the TableRow and each image and text as `layout_weight=0.2` (considering the 0.8 for the entire table).

**All of which gave the same result, the leftmost image always disappearing to the left and the texts not being aligned with the images.**

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_seeding_rect"
                android:tooltipText="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonRead"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_seeding_rect"
                android:tooltipText="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonReply"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_seeding_rect"
                android:tooltipText="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonForward"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_seeding_rect"
                android:tooltipText="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="text1"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="text1"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="text1"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="text1"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Remaining 20 %"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to make any difference...

Comment: updated my answer, remove both android:stretchColumns weightSum

Comment: The three first images grew bigger, but the fourth is still out of bounds and the texts aren't aligned with the images :(

Comment: updated my answer and I have added code. I have tried and its working as per your requirement

Comment: It does work like this, since in your code the TableLayout stands by itself, whereas mine is inside a LinearLayout in order for the table to take 80% page width.
If I change the table `layout_width` to `match_parent`, everything fits in perfectly.
Have you any idea how to make the same thing work within the 80% width limit?

Comment: Check the updated answer . if it helps you please accept it

Comment: It sorts of works with the same image 4 times, when I changed the `src` to different images it went berserk again.
Also, seems the outer LinearLayout should have an `orientation="horizontal"` rather than vertical, since the remaining 20% you added goes to the bottom instead of filling the remaining width.
Still, the text isn't aligned with the images.
I'll try to take it from here and post my code if it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a little cheating,

Two LinearLayouts (one for each row) proved much more effective and easily understandable.

- I've defined each LinearLayout with `weightSum="1"` and with a `layout_width="match_parent"` - taking up the entire page width.
- Each image or text got `layout_weight="0.2"` (for a total of 80% of page width, leaving 20% for margins as desired).

Here is the working code:

```html
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/greyexclamation_trans"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonRead"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonReply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_reply_24"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonForward"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_forward_to_inbox_24"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUrgent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="text1"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRead"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="text2"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewReply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="text3"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForward"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="text4"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks [End User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10033423/end-user) for helping to spot some of the problems with the TableLayout.